# RestSharp client.post vs client.execute

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm starting to use RestSharp POST with c# and dot net. However, I'm not sure what the difference is in client.Execute and client.Post.

Answer (score 2):

The code below:

```
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("apiEndPoint", Method.POST);
IRestResponse response = RestClient.Execute(request);
```

And this one:

```
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("apiEndPoint");
IRestResponse response = RestClient.Post(request);
```

Both send the same HTTP request with a POST verb to an URL server/`apiEndPoint`.

Both are valid and you should use one instead of another based on your implementation design. I tend to use the first one because I usually know the verb (POST, GET, ...) before execution.